# Como fazer um reduce de valores decimais?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Preciso utilizar o método do `reduce` em JavaScript, pois preciso realizar a somatória de vários valores simultâneos que estão contidos em um array.

Como estou utilizando TypeScript (Ionic3), os tipos dessas variáveis são `number`, e não `float` ou `double`.

Quando executo o `reduce` com números inteiros, tudo ocorre bem e retorna o valor da soma.

Porém quando executo um valor decimal por exemplo **10,00 + 10,00** ele me retorna NAN.

Existe alguma diferença entre realizar um `reduce` de valores decimais e inteiros?

Comment: O correto não seria `10.00`?

Comment: Mostre o código onde é feita a soma.